# Problem in Powershell with the --runtime command setting up Jenkins pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, jenkins

I am trying to configure a Pipeline with Jenkins and deploying it to Azure. I am at the last step of a tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/tutorial-jenkins-deploy-web-app-azure-app-service

This last step is as follows, i have to enter this in the Azure CLI:

```
az group create --name yourWebAppAzureResourceGroupName --location region
az appservice plan create --name appServicePlanName --resource-group rgname --is-linux
az webapp create --name webAppName --resource-group rgName --plan appServicePlanName --runtime "java|1.8|Tomcat|8.5"
```

The last command gives me the error:

'1.8' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

So I thought maybe Tomcat is not installed on my Azure VM, which is a Linux machine. So I used the next tutorial to install Tomcat:

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-5-on-ubuntu-16-04/

After this I tried to do the --runtime command again, but I still get the same error. I have no idea how to fix this. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

I tried to check the webapp list-runtimes and I get this list:

[image]

"java|1.8|Tomcat|8.5" is in here. I've tried all of the versions, but it did not work.

EDIT: It works in the Azure Cloud Shell, but then there is another error:

```
Linux Runtime 'java|1.8|Tomcat|8.5' is not supported.Please invoke 'list-runtimes' to cross check
```

I have tried all the runtime versions, but still this error. I have also tried it with double quotes

Comment: try `'` around your string instead of `"`?

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I still get the same error.

Comment: ok, try `'java\|1.8\|Tomcat\|8.5'`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives almost the same error, but now : '1.8\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: weird, I'm sure it's escaping problem

Comment: It looks like it does not want to accept the 1.x number.

Comment: did you use \ for line breaks? I noticed in your original question you just inserted linebreaks. also why do you mention powershell?

Comment: Do you mean this line?: az webapp create --name webAppName --resource-group rgName \
  --plan appServicePlanName --runtime "java|1.8|Tomcat|8.5"

this is not correct, it should be: 

az webapp create --name yourWebAppName --resource-group yourWebAppAzureResourceGroupName --plan yourLinuxAppServicePlanName --runtime "java|1.8|Tomcat|8.5" 

Without any linebreaks.

I am doing these commands in a PowerShell terminal.

Comment: Ok I tried it in the Azure Cloud Shell now, and I get a different error now:

Linux Runtime 'java|1.8|Tomcat|8.5' is not supported.Please invoke 'list-runtimes' to cross check

So I once again tried all of the version but still not supported. So TomCat is not installed on the vm?

Comment: you dont have a vm anywhere, you have appservice. its weird you get that error. try checking supported runtimes in azure cloud shell?

Comment: The list is pretty much the same in azure cloud shell. None of the runtimes work.

Comment: no idea, looks really weird (like a bug, tbh). but I'm not a big `az` user, so cant tell for sure. behaviour is exactly the same for me in cloud shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i got it, that list is for windows webapp, not linux. for linux use:

```
az webapp list-runtimes --linux
```

so working solution:

```
az webapp create --name yourWebAppName --resource-group yourWebAppAzureResourceGroupName --plan yourLinuxAppServicePlanName --runtime "TOMCAT|8.5-jre8"
```

Comment: This is correct, it works now, but you are missing the 's', it should be:

az webapp list-runtimes --linux 

Tried to edit but it has to be reviewed, maybe it is faster that you edit it. Then I can approve this answer.

Comment: When I use this: 

az webapp create --name yourWebAppName --resource-group yourWebAppAzureResourceGroupName --plan yourLinuxAppServicePlanName --runtime "TOMCAT|8.5-jre8"
It works.

Answer (score 5):

I bet you solved your problem already, but in case others find this and are using **PowerShell** to run **Azure CLI** commands. This is what worked for me.

The problem is in how PowerShell interprets the pipe, `'|'`, character inside the `--runtime` parameter, when evaluating the whole line.

Add the `--%` to be beginning of the command to turn off PowerShell evaluation of expressions, as suggested in the code block [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-dotnetcore#create-a-web-app).

**Note**: this will also stop PowerShell from evaluating any variables inside the command. What you can do is move the `--runtime` to the end of the line to get around this problem, e.g. like this

```
az webapp create -g $rg -p $appPlanName -n $appName --deployment-local-git --% --runtime "DOTNETCORE|3.0"
```