# az webapp list-runtimes - Powershell equivalent

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

Does anyone know if there is any equivalent for the az cli command "az webapp list-runtimes" in PowerShell?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this thread and see if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863650/problem-in-powershell-with-the-runtime-command-setting-up-jenkins-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

There is none I am aware of. However you can anyway fire `az` cmd from the same powershell session seamlessly if you are already into latest [Az powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/azure/).

```
$rt = az webapp list-runtimes # for linux, add --linux flag
# use $rt like a regular ps variable (would be array in this case)
```